# Rails query changes the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, timezone, mongoid

```
<% date = Time.now.beginning_of_day %>
<%= date %> prints 2016-06-01 00:00:00 +0600
<% schedule = Schedule.where(:date_ => date).first %>
<%= date %> prints 2016-05-31 18:00:00 UTC
```

**2016-06-01 00:00:00 +0600**

**2016-05-31 18:00:00 UTC**

Using mongoid

date_ is Time field

My local timezone is UTC +6

*I am sorry if my question is stupid -_-'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ Time.now
#⇒ 2016-06-26 07:43:42 +0200
▶ Time.now.utc
#⇒ 2016-06-26 05:43:46 UTC
```

That said, `2016-06-01 00:00:00 +0600` and `2016-05-31 18:00:00 UTC` you got are *the same time*, printed in different timezones.

In Rails you should always explicitly define a timezone you are dealing in:

```
Time.now # incorrect
Time.zone.now # correct
```

Further reading: http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/